How to work with embedded fragments of code?
Many editors and linters can handle code with embedded code in another language, but sometimes we have only fragments of code. These can confuse linters and can for example break inspection error reporting, or break tools like code completion.
Nomenclature is a bit of a challenge here, a quick example probably helps.

Please don't focus on why this example code is as it is, or how it could be better.
(e.g. please no "use a query builder!", what if I'm writing the query builder?)
The example is SQL fragments in PHP, but it could also be HTML or CSS fragments in JS, or some other embedded language.
The point is if a fragmented construction like this is used, how do we work with it.

Consider some PHP with SQL queries in strings:

    // ...

    $conditions = ' 1 ';
    $params = [];

    if ($min_age) {
        $conditions .= ' AND age >= :min_age ';
        $params['min_age'] = $min_age;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE {$conditions} ORDER BY name LIMIT 50";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    // ...


This is just a small example. Assume the conditions and query are more complex, and writing out all variations as full queries is impractical.
Usually interfaces and linters have no problem with this part:
    $query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE {$conditions} ORDER BY name LIMIT 50";

They can highlight keywords, code completion for table names work fine, etc.
But this part tends to confuse linters:
        $conditions .= ' AND age >= :min_age ';

Sometimes it does nothing, sometimes it just works, but often it detects it to be SQL but then trips on incomplete syntax.
For example in this case it reports the syntax error:
'(', ':', ':=', '=' or '[' expected, got 'age' .

Is there a pattern we can use to improve on this?
We could prefix the fragments with things like /** @noinspection */ to suppress errors, but we might miss something we really did do wrong in the fragment, or something changed elsewhere.
Is there a way to signal what kind of fragment to handle?
Perhaps even a way to signal how fragments fit together?

I've tried looking around for solutions or even mentions of this, but it seems I don't know what nomenclature to search for, or maybe there is nothing to find.
For example; Jetbrains calls embedded code "Language injections" in their documentation, but searching for that results in a lot of hits on malicious code injections. Similarly "code fragments" results in all kinds of things, but not what I'm looking for.
I struggled to find a question tag. I went for "code-structure" but that isn't quite it.  Tags like "embedded", "fragment", "design pattern", "markup" seem to miss the mark, and "phpdoc", "jsdoc", "php", "sql" miss on the general nature of this issue.
I'm using PHP with SQL here as example (and I tend to use PhpStorm (Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA) IDE), but I've encountered similar issues with HTML or CSS in JS for example, and I'm sure there are more variations on this theme. I'd rather not tag this question for PHP or SQL only, I'm looking for a more general approach to handle this.
If you can suggest what nomenclature I should use, or what others might search for, I can update the question, title and tags to help with finding this.

This question may be better on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange site instead. It's not about a specific problem and it's asking several opinion-based questions, so it's likely to be closed here.
